# C#, property from parent class not included in serialised child class instance

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public String Manufacturer;
}

public class Train : Vehicle
{
    public int MaxNumberOfWagons;
}

var aTrain = new Train();
aTrain.Manufacturer = "RailCorpMurica";
aTrain.MaxNumberOfWagons = 30;
var aTrainJson = serialiser.Serialise(aTrain);

//aTrainJson does not have the Manufacturer property?
```

I am trying to serialise `aTrain` to json. The result contains the MaxNumberOfWagons key and value. But the manufacture is not included.

How can I include the manufacture without touching the `Vehicle` class?

Comment: what serialiser are you using?

Comment: what kind of serialization are you using? What's the type of `serialiser`?

Comment: @algorithmicMoose i am doing the serialisation through my company framework, whose pipes I cannot access, nor expose if I could.

Comment: There is no way we can help you solve an issue with your own framework.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yes, assuming the issue is with the Serialiser, and not anything to do with with, maybe adding something to the child class to tell it to include the property in any form of serialisation, hence my question here

Comment: It's up to the framework to decide how to find stuff that needs to be serialized (fields, properties) and where to look for it (only given class, or all of class hierarchy). It's up to the framework to use attributes or other methods to change serialization behavior. So the serializer is where you should look for answers.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you serializing the object? Following code should be able to get what you want:

```
 var aTrainJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(aTrain);
```

make sure you add reference to System.Web.Extension.